# Nodejs request module returning XML for Facebook Graph API FQL query, I need JSON

Tags: javascript, facebook, node.js, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the `request` module for node.js to do a Facebook FQL query. The problem is it's returning the results as XML instead of a JSON object. I'm not sure if this is something that needs to be set for the `request` module or something that needs to be added to my query. All the Google results I find say JSON is the default return format.

```
var request = require('request');
request({
        url: 'https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT%20current_location%20FROM%20user%20WHERE%20uid=' + fb_id + '&access_token=' + fb_token,
        json: true
    },
    function (error, response, body){
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200){
            console.log(body);
        }
    }
);
```

**EDIT:**

Got it figured out finally. I had to use a different URL. The one I was using was outdated.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/fql?q=SELECT%20current_location%20FROM%20user%20WHERE%20uid=' + fb_id + '&access_token=' + fb_token
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it figured out. I was using an outdated URL. Here is the correct URL to use:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/fql?q=SELECT%20current_location%20FROM%20user%20WHERE%20uid=' + fb_id + '&access_token=' + fb_token
```